# How to disable GPIO pins on the RaspberryPi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

Basically, I need to disable or turn off a `GPIO` pin whenever I execute a method in `python`.

Does anyone knows how to disable the pins?

Comment: Maybe http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place for your question

Comment: What do you mean by disable or off?

Comment: @FengHao Meaning i cannot touch that gpio pin when ever any event happen.

Comment: If you did not set the GPIO pins, the pins won't have any effect.

Comment: @FengHao I know that. Because i am making a project that requires to disable the GPIO pins when i do certain methods than to enable the GPIO pins again when i do another method

Comment: You could try GPIO.cleanup() in one method, and reset all your pins and event detection in another method.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in function GPIO.cleanup() that clean up all the ports you've used.
For the power and ground pins, they are not under software control.